# Override ctrl-arrows with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use ctrl-right and ctrl-down for a browser app. In OS X, this leads to going one desktop to the right or tiling all of the windows on the current desktop. I'm trying to use `e.preventDefault();`, but it's not working; the OS functions are still happening. Is there any way to override those functions?

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) { //For any other keypress event
  if (e.which == 39) { //Checking if it's right arrow
    if(ctrlPressed == true){
        //spread score across kid's standards
        e.preventDefault();
        var kid = $(':focus').attr('kidid');
        var score = $(':focus').val();
        $('.SmallInput[kidid='+kid+']').each(function(index) {
        ScoreEntry($(this),score);
    });
    ctrlPressed = false;
  }
  } else if (e.which == 40) { //down arrow
    if(ctrlPressed == true){
        e.preventDefault();
        //spread score down standard - all kids
        var std = $(':focus').attr('stdid');
        var score = $(':focus').val();
        $('.SmallInput[stdid='+std+']').each(function(index) {
        ScoreEntry($(this),score);
    });
    ctrlPressed = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: Seemed like where it'd end up, but thought I'd ask! I didn't see anything here addressing this, so maybe this'll help someone in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed not possible.

Where I went with for this was to use the command key (test for `.metaKey()`) on OS X and ctrl for Windows.